# .htaccess throws Internal server error for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have created a subdomain comments.yoursite.com to deploy a commenting plugin for the main site www.yoursite.com. Whenever I point my browser to the comments.yoursite.com/app/install.php or comments.yoursite.com  it throws Internal error

**My .htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

**File structure:**
Main site: home/yoursite/public_html/public
Comments plugin: home/yoursite/comments

When I delete the htaccess file the comments plugin works but the main site shows Not found. Cant get them both working at the same time :(

I am using Laravel.

Please help O_o

Comment: Internal Server Errors are being logged in the server logs. Please show us the error message.

Comment: [Sun May 01 00:15:22.472696 2016] [core:alert] [pid 558607:tid 139761515673344] [client 94.173.202.90:55438] /home/antonsirik/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad argument line '^(.*)$'
[Sun May 01 00:15:22.472587 2016] [core:alert] [pid 558607:tid 139761515673344] [client 94.173.202.90:55438] /home/antonsirik/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad argument line '^(.*)$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need two distinct `RewriteCond`ition(s) and rules for the two use cases - try something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^comments.yoursite.com
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursite.com/comments/$1 [NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: comments now work but the main site gets 404 -Not found :( Error Log: [Sun May 01 00:02:13.784769 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 561887:tid 139761641551616] [client 94.173.202.90:55206] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/antonsirik/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html...) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/antonsirik/public_html/comments] does not exist

Comment: So should the main content of your site be served under /? What happens when you remove the second rule/condition?

Comment: Main content of the site should be under /. When I removed second rule/condition I get Comments section working, the main site gets Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Bueno, I updated the second rule accordingly - give it a try

Comment: Reto, comments plugin works, but the main site is Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: This is another (configuration) issue then. It has nothing to do with the rewrite ;)

Comment: any idea where to start looking into?

Comment: Difficult to  say, but it is very likely related to file/directory permissions/ownership and/or apache configuration.

Comment: Ohh yeah! Got it! Thanks for pointing at the right direction. The file structure was causing this problem. I took the folder "Comments" out of public to the same level. Now it works!

Comment: this is what the working structure looks like: /home/yoursite/comments (for comments plugin) and /home/yoursite/public (for main site files)